# How to make a slide up modal page in Meego?

Tags: qt, qml, meego-harmattan

I'm developing an app which works more or less like the Notes app. When user click the + button a modal window with TextEdits is to be slided up，just like the Notes app did. However I was unable to locate any resource mentioning this kind of thing. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the QML [Sheet](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt-components/qt-components-meego-sheet.html) element. You will need to implement the TextEdit part yourself.